# Column filtering in cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Hello I was wondering if someone with some knowledge of Cassandra could help me. Right now i'm investigating the read path of Cassandra using a debugger but for some reason cannot find the specific place where the columns for a row are filtered with respect to the query.

I have issued both queries:

"select * from tabl where name1='rowkey8888';"

and

"select name9 from tabl where name1='rowkey999211';"

What is confusing to me is that they are both considered SliceFromReadCommand commands and the 
SliceQueryFilter object associated with the command is the same for both: [reversed=false, slices=[[, ]], count=10000, toGroup = 0]

My question is that can anyone explain to me the reason for this behaviour, as I was under the impression when a column name was given in the query (name9 in the above case) then
the command would be a SliceByNamesReadCommand and the specified columns would be in the QueryFilter slices array. Additionally would anyone be able to point out where this filtering is done as I cannot find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [reasons related to TTL handling](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5762), C* actually has to query a "slice" of the partition even when you give it a specific name.

[CollationController](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/CollationController.java) is a good place to start code diving.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still wondering though where the actually filtering is done for the actual column requested. As I get to the point in getColumnFamily(QueryFilter filter) method within the ColumnFamilyStore class. where the line (1306) 

ColumnFamily cf = getTopLevelColumns(filter, gcBefore);

cf contains all columns at that point and I see no filtering done following that.